# Using parameterized query is causing data type mismatch. Any ideas?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access-2010

I have a dropdownList with control ID of HourlyCharter.

Then on codebehind, I am trying to query records from the database where hourly is equal to the value of HourlyCharter.

If I use this code:

```
    StrSQL = "select h.fare, h.tip, h.total from hourlyQRY h "
    StrSQL += " Where h.Hourly = " & HourlyCharter.SelectedValue

' Initialize Database Connection
Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ALSConnectionString").ConnectionString
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr)
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(StrSQL, conn)
```

It works.

If I use parameterized query such as this:

```
    StrSQL = "select h.fare, h.tip, h.total from hourlyQRY h "
    StrSQL += " Where h.Hourly = @hourly"

' Initialize Database Connection
Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ALSConnectionString").ConnectionString
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr)
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(StrSQL, conn)

'We use parametized query to prevent sql injection attack
Dim p1 As New OleDbParameter("@hourly", HourlyCharter.SelectedValue)
```

cmd.Parameters.Add(p1)

I get following error:

**Data type mismatch in criteria expression**

Hourly is of Number data type and we are using Access 2010 database.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

```
    'open recordset to receive db values
rs = cmd.ExecuteReader()

' This acts like the (Not RecordSource.Eof) in ASP 3.0 to loop and retrieve records.
While rs.Read()
    '    If rs("city") <> "" Then
    Dim tipValue As Decimal = rs("tip")
    Dim totValue = rs("total")
    '   Else
    '   End If
    Dim tp As String = [String].Format("{0:C}", tipValue)
    Dim tot As String = [String].Format("{0:C}", totValue)
    lblTip.Text = tp
    lblTotal.Text = tot

End While
```

Comment: You don't need to put braces on `[String]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
Dim p1 As New OleDbParameter("@hourly", HourlyCharter.SelectedValue)
cmd.Parameters.Add(p1)
```

You can try

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hourly", HourlyCharter.SelectedValue)
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why this worked but it worked!

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the object you put in the parameter is also a numeric type. `SelectedValue` is a string.

```
Dim p1 As New OleDbParameter("@hourly", Decimal.Parse(HourlyCharter.SelectedValue))
```

That's where the data type mismatch happens - it's expecting a number but it's getting a string.

Comment: thanks a lot for the prompt response. I am still getting the error. Perhaps, I should point out that the error is on this line:

rs = cmd.ExecuteReader().

I have updated code above

Comment: I haven't used Access in awhile, but I believe there are different number types (integer, float, etc.). Whichever one you're using, your parameter value has to be of that type.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the datat type of the parameter. You can do it after creating it:

```
p1.OleDbType = OleDb.OleDbType.Numeric
```

You can also do it on the constructor, but it requires a lot more parameters and I'm not sure you have all those nor I do know what they do.